# Regular expression in HP Loadrunner

Tags: regex, loadrunner

we are using HP loadrunner in order to run performance test on a web application. In the script we have some items like:

```
    ITEMDATA, 
    "Name=ROW_LIST_CODE$367$", "Value=", ENDITEM,
```

Every istallation of the software the $367$ value change with a different number and the LR script fails.
Is there a method to susbtitute it with regular expression?
Thank you!

Comment: The information is incomplete to assist. Is the number 367 randomly generated ? Is it response from some previous request ? Do you already have the data for next request ?
Please provide the above info to solve this problem.

Comment: The number is generated by the software under test when it renders the page. I don't know how and it isn't a response of a previous request. It seems to be a sort of ordinal regarding the position of objects on page.

Comment: I don't think if you replace the number with a regular expression will solve the problem, because the server will be expecting the exact value 367. We need to have the next number somehow to automate it.

Answer (score 0):

Is the 367 a [nonce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce)?

The server sends a unique value on each transaction that must be supplied on the very next transaction.  This is used to prevent replay attacks.  Of course LoadRunner is a replay engine so the most important LR command is **Web_reg_save_param**.  See [web_reg_save_param function explained](http://learnloadrunner.com/correlation/web_reg_save_param-function-explained/)